# Set Color to a TextView

Tags: android, xml, colors, textview

I know it sounds dumb but every time i try to setTextColor to a textview with my own colors it never does it .

```
 TextView tv;
    tv.setTextColor(color.blue_light);
```

doesn't work . The only thing that works is Android's own colors with the  Color.BLUE, Color.RED attributs etc .

colors.xml looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <color name="blue_light">#2D9DC8</color>
  <color name="blue_dark">#314d61</color>
  <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
  <color name="green_light">#308A24</color>
  <color name="black">#000000</color>
  <color name="black_light">#333</color>
  <color name="grey_light">#A1A1A1</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Should be:

```
setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_light));
```

Comment: Okay thank you it was this one . I need to wait to validate this answer .

Answer (score 0):

You probably need (notice the `R.` part):

```
tv.setTextColor(R.color.blue_light);
```

Comment: i don't know why but it make something odd, normally it's gray, but light gray . But when i tried that, it was dark gray .

Comment: it's wrong. you assing int which is a identifier and not a color. You need to load the value from this identifier.

Comment: @Damian argh, I always get fooled by that, sorry. +1 to you

Comment: @Felix no problem. I always make mistake with ints : { int a = 0 ; textView.setText(a); } it will not display "0".
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
TextView tv;
tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
```

desc:

rgb (int red, int green, int blue) 
 These component values should be [0..255]

Answer (score 0):

```
tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#F5AC39"));
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple! If you are looking for common colors, use it this way

tv.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

There are a lot of common colors..

Comment: OP stated he is trying to use his own colors, not only that which are provided by android.